# "The trial period for this product has expired" after a repair

Tags: error

I had to perform a repair on my SharePoint. Since doing this I now get the error "The trial period for this product has expired." when I try try to add a document. What do I do? I have a valid key.

Answer (score 1):

Did you run the Farm Configuration Wizard after the repair?

Comment: No I did not run the Farm Configuration Wizard

Comment: Maybe you could try?

Answer (score 0):

This issue may cause three reasons.. here is the post to fix this issue...

http://sureshpydi.blogspot.in/2013/03/share-point-trial-period-for-this.html